# Not getting any value in $_POST after from submit

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, post

I am facing a problem in my local wamp server while submitting a page in PHP
I am using post method and after submitting the form I am not getting any values in $_POST.
I searched a lot on internet but did not get any good solution.
Here is my code

```
<form name="form_modulesadd" id="form_modulesadd" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="#" class="form-horizontal" >

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-md-2">Module Type<span class="required_mark">*</span></label>
            <div class="col-md-7">
                <select id="module_t" name="module_t" class="form-control" onchange="getProductName()">
                    <option value="">Select Module Type</option>
                    <option value="1" <?php if($data['module_type'] == '1'){ echo 'selected'; } ?> >Video Module</option>
                    <option value="2" <?php if($data['module_type'] == '2'){ echo 'selected'; } ?> >Qbank Module</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div> 

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-md-2">Product Name<span class="required_mark">*</span></label>
            <div class="col-md-7">
                <select  id="moduleajax" name="product_n" class="form-control" onchange="getProductData()">
                    <option  value="">Select Product Name</option>
                    <?php 
                        foreach($result_product1 as $k => $data_p)
                        {
                            $selected = ($data['productId'] == $data_p['id'])?'selected': '';
                            echo '<option '. $selected .' value='.$data_p['id'].'>' . $data_p['product_name'] . '</option>';
                        }
                    ?>
                </select>           
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="productajax">
        </div>

        <?php
            if(!empty($data))
            {
                $qry_s="SELECT * FROM tbl_products WHERE status =1 and id='".$data['productId']."'";
                $result_s = $modelObj->fetchRow($qry_s);

                $qry = "SELECT name FROM tbl_category WHERE id = '".$result_s['categoryId']."'";
                $data1 = $modelObj->fetchRow($qry);
        ?>

        <div id="productHide">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-md-2">Category Name</label>
                <div class="col-md-7">
                    <input class="form-control" onkeydown="call(event,this.id)" type="text" value="<?php echo $data1['name'] ?>" disabled/>
                </div>
                <br><br>
                <label class="control-label col-md-2">Price</label>
                <div class="col-md-7">
                    <input class="form-control" onkeydown="call(event,this.id)" type="text" value="<?php echo $result_s['p_price'] ?>" disabled/>
                </div><br><Br>
                <label class="control-label col-md-2">Maximum Attempts</label>
                <div class="col-md-7">
                    <input class="form-control" onkeydown="call(event,this.id)" type="text" value="<?php echo $result_s['p_max_attempt'] ?>" disabled/>
                </div><br><Br>
                <?php if($data['module_type'] == '2') { ?>
                    <label class="control-label col-md-2">Exam Hour</label>
                    <div class="col-md-7">
                        <input class="form-control" onkeydown="call(event,this.id)" type="text" value="<?php echo $result_s['exam_hour'] ?>" disabled/>
                    </div><br><br>
                    <label class="control-label col-md-2">Pass mark or question</label>
                    <div class="col-md-7">
                        <input class="form-control" onkeydown="call(event,this.id)" type="text" value="<?php echo $result_s['pass_mark'] ?>" disabled/>
                    </div>
                <?php } ?>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php } ?>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-md-2">Module Name<span class="required_mark">*</span></label>
            <div class="col-md-7">
                <input class="form-control" placeholder="Module Name" onkeydown="call(event,this.id)" type="text" name="txt_addmodulename" maxlength = "50" id="txt_addmodulename" value="<?php echo stripslashes($data['module_name']) ?>"/>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="str_video" style="display: none;">
            <div id="nameBoxWrap_d1">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-md-2">Module Video<span class="required_mark">*</span></label>
                    <div class="col-md-7">
                        <div class="fileupload fileupload-new" data-provides="fileupload">
                            <div> 
                                <span class="btn btn-default btn-file"><span class="fileupload-new">Select Video</span><span class="fileupload-exists">Change</span>
                                    <input type="file" name="name_dig[]" id="name_d1">
                                </span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                <span class="video_image_class">Video Image</span>
                                <input style="padding-right: 230px; float: right; margin-top: 3px;" type="file" name="name_vi[]" id="name_vi1">
                                <br><br><input type="button" value="Addmore Video" onclick="addNameSection1()" class="btn btn-primary" style="background-color: green;">
                                <b>Only .mp4, .flv, .ogg, .webm Video support</b>                           
                            </div>                          
                        </div>                          
                    </div>
                <input type="hidden" id="addSectionCount1" value="1" name="addSectionCount1">
            </div>
        <?php 
            if(!empty($data))
            {
            ?>
            <div id="fileajax">
                <div class="form-group" >
                    <label class="control-label col-md-2"> </label>
                    <div class="col-md-7">
                <?php
                    $qry = "SELECT * FROM tbl_module_video WHERE moduleId = '".$_POST['id']."'";
                    $data_fl = $modelObj->fetchRows($qry);
                    foreach($data_fl as $d => $dav)
                    {
                    ?>
                        <a href="<?php echo $_SESSION['FRNT_DOMAIN_NAME']."views/videos/".$dav['image']; ?>"> <img width="50" src="<?php echo $_SESSION['FRNT_DOMAIN_NAME']."upload/module/".$dav['video_image'] ?>"> </a>
                        <button type="button" class="label label-danger" onclick="deletevd('<?php echo $dav['id'] ?>','<?php echo $_POST['id'] ?>');">Delete</button>
                <?php } ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php } ?>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!--<div id="str_video1">
        <div id="nameBoxWrap_v1">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-md-2"></label>
                <div class="col-md-7">
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        <div class="fileupload fileupload-new" data-provides="fileupload">
                            <div class="fileupload-new img-thumbnail" style="width: 200px; height: 125px;">
                            <img src="http://www.placehold.it/200x150/EFEFEF/AAAAAA&text=no+image">
                            </div>
                            <div class="fileupload-preview fileupload-exists img-thumbnail" style="width: 200px; max-height: 125px"></div>
                            <div> 
                                <span class="btn btn-default btn-file">
                                    <span class="fileupload-new">Select Video Image</span><span class="fileupload-exists">Change</span>
                                    <input type="file" name="name_vi" id="name_vi1" accept="image/*">
                                </span>
                                <a class="btn btn-default fileupload-exists" data-dismiss="fileupload" href="#">Remove</a> 
                            </div>                                  
                        </div>                          
                    </div>
                </div>
                <input type="hidden" id="addSectionCount1" value="1" name="addSectionCount1">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>-->

      <?php if($_POST['id'] !=0):?>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-2"></label>
        <div class="col-md-7">
          <input type="hidden" name="hid_userid" id="hid_userid" value="<?php echo $data['id'] ?>" />
          <input type="hidden" name="hid_update" id="hid_update" value="update" />
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="return updatedata()">Submit</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default-outline" onclick="newdata();">Cancel</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <?php else:?>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-2"></label>
        <div class="col-md-7">
          <input type="hidden" name="hid_add" id="hid_add" value="1" />
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="return adddata()">Submit</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default-outline" onclick="newdata();">Cancel</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <?php endif;?>
    </form>
```

And here is my javascript from which I am call the page

```
var options = {
    beforeSubmit: showRequest,
    success: showResponse,
    url: site_url + 'controllers/ajax_controller/modules-ajax-controller.php',
    type: "POST"
};
$('#form_modulesadd').submit(function() {
    $(this).ajaxSubmit(options);
    return false;
});
```

after submitting the page I am not getting any values in $_POST
this code is working fine in the server.
In local Environment it's giving problem
I am using wamp server. I have already tried with `var_dump()`,`print_r()`  but not getting any result.
Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `data` option to send the data to the server.

```
var options = {
   ...
   data: $('#form_modulesadd').serialize(),
   ...

};
```

`$('#form_modulesadd').serialize()` will send the data from the form.

**EDIT**

Try `ajax`:

```
$('#form_modulesadd').submit(function() {
    $.ajax(options);
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Hi Tushar I am doing the same thing still not getting any values

Answer (score 4):

In your options, you should specify the `data` that you want to send.

```
var options = {
    beforeSubmit: showRequest,
    success: showResponse,
    url: site_url + 'controllers/ajax_controller/modules-ajax-controller.php',
    type: "POST",
    data: {data1: "your_data", data2: "your_data"}
};
```

Then, try:

```
<?php echo $_POST["data1"]; ?>
```

It will show the data send, here: `your_data`

Answer (score 0):

use `<form name="form_modulesadd" id="form_modulesadd" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<?=site_url?>controllers/ajax_controller/modules-ajax-controller.php'" class="form-horizontal" >`